# Windows Explorer sometimes opens multiple windows when navigating to a folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Sometimes, after double clicking on a folder, Windows Explorer will open 2 or more new windows of the folder I was trying to navigate to. I've noticed this happens with folders on the desktop and items in the Quick access column. I've ensured that "Open each folder in its own window" is **not** selected. Why does Windows want to test my patience and how can I prevent this issue from occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is related to the quick export function of Adobe Photoshop CC. A quick registry fix is all that's needed.

Close all instances of Windows Explorer and open `regedit`. Delete the following registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Modules\NavPane
```

It will be recreated upon opening Windows Explorer and the multiple windows issue will no longer persist.